# how store in hash table in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to store array or linked list in hash table EX:

```
       array [,] m = new array(){"doucument",13.4}; 
       hashtable h = new hashtable();
       h.add(1,m );
```

please help me how store this array in hashtable,and If I can, how access to element this array?
Error:  A nested array initializer is expected  in line 1

```
                     array [,] m = new array(){"doucument",13.4};
```

Comment: Are you talking about the non-generic `Hashtable` class back from .NET 1.1? Any reason not to use a `Dictionary<,>`? It's also not really clear exactly what the types involved are... if you could put a bit more effort into a more complete example, I suspect we could help more.

Comment: You're example doesn't look like c#.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, object[]>();
  dictionary.Add(1, new object[] {"doucument",13.4});

  var arr = dictionary[1];
```

Comment: can you explain this: var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, object>();

Comment: @xxxman it basically creates a dictionary from integer to object array. The var keywords indicates that the type of the instance if inferred by the compiler. It's equivalent (but less wordy) to Dictionary<int, object[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, object[]>();

Answer (score 0):

from your question it wasn't obvious if this is a key-value collection or just values. Just to throw it in there, you should know that with .NET 3.5 and up, you can use a HashSet, example:

```
HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get your syntax errors out of your code and it will work fine:

```
       using System.Collections;

       Array[,] m = new Array[,]{"document",13.4}; 
       Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
       h.Add(1,m );
```

Accessing the stored element:

```
       m = (Array[,])h[1];
```

Of course, personally I would prefer the use of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`;

Comment: Array[,] m = new Array[,] { "document", 13.4 };Error 1 A nested array initializer is expected